# Can i show the html i scrape from url parameter in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, web-scraping

I want to scrape html and modify some values and show as its.

I don't mean that i want to scrape some elements in the html.

can somebody help me?

Comment: @haxtbh i haven't tried anything. i don't know how to start code first

Comment: @haxtbh u know, just like google' translate web, i want to scrap all of html from url

Comment: This site is for asking for help with things you have already done. Not for requests on doing it for you.